# The set of non-zero-divisors is dense in the $\mathfrak m$-adic topology for a Noetherian local ring of positive depth

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

> Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring with at least one non-zero-divisors in $\mathfrak m$. Let $a\in \mathfrak m$ and $p\in \mathbb N$. Then we can find $a'\in \mathfrak m^p$ such that $a+a'$ is a non-zero-divisor.

By this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228714/for-a-noetherian-local-ring-of-positive-depth-the-maximal-ideal-can-be-generate) we know $\mathfrak m$ can be generated by nonzero divisors, hence so is any power of $\mathfrak m$. Let $k$ be such that $a\in \mathfrak m^k\setminus \mathfrak m^{k+1}$. Then we can write $a=\sum r_im_i$, $m_i\in \mathfrak m^k$ nonzerodivisors. Then since $a\notin \mathfrak m^{k+1}$, at least one $r_j$ must lie outside $\mathfrak m$, hence invertible. The $a-\sum_{i\neq j} r_im_i=r_jm_j$ is a non-zero-divisor. So this settles the question for $p\le k$. But can this idea be pushed further to show for $p> k$ or is there any other approach? Thanks.

Comment: Can the nonzero divisor in the hypothesis be 1?

Comment: The question you linked has the additional hypothesis of 'positive depth'. Without this, we don't know $m$ can be generated by nonzero divisors, e.g. the dual numbers $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2)$ are a Noetherian local ring where the maximal ideal is all zero divisors.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak p_1,...\mathfrak p_s$ be all the associated primes and we can assume they are incomparable by discarding the ones contained in the others (since we only care about their union). We list them in such a way that $a\in \mathfrak p_1\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak p_r$ and $a\notin \mathfrak p_{r+1}\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_s$ for $0\le r\le s$. Then since $R$ has positive depth, we can pick $b\in \mathfrak m^p\setminus (\mathfrak p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_s)$. By prime avoidance, we can also pick $c\in (\mathfrak p_{r+1}\cap\cdots\cap \mathfrak p_s)\setminus (p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_r)$. Then $a':=bc\in \mathfrak m^p$ satisfies $a+a'\notin \mathfrak p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_s$ , so it is not a zero divisor.

Comment: To pick $c$, you only need the hypothesis that any two $p_i$ are incomparable. Since we are dealing with unions, we can always discard the smaller ones and assume all $p_i$ are incomparable from the start.

Comment: @cqfd Yeah, that's correct. Thanks.